# .HTACCESS Rewriting Issue

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Can any check given code of .htaccess file and let me know what's wrong with it and why it's not working?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^itinerary/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\$ itinerary-details.php?tId=$2
```

I want to rewrite url as below:

> www.domain.com/itinerary-details.php?tId=2&tName=agra-delhi-tour

to

> www.domain.com/itinerary/2/agra-delhi-tour

---

and

> www.domain.com/itinerary-details.php?page=1&tId=2&tName=agra-delhi-tour

to

> www.domain.com/itinerary/2/agra-delhi-tour/1

Please help me in doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have the two sections in your regex reversed.  This should work for both your cases:

```
^itinerary/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?(.*) itinerary-details.php?tId=$1&tName=$2&page=$3
```

I also just noticed that you were escaping the `$` which would also cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^itinerary/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /itinerary-details.php?tId=$1&tName=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^itinerary/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /itinerary-details.php?page=$3&tId=$1&tName=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```